# How to parse the different type of json

Tags: android, kotlin

When I call an api with specific parameter, I get a json like this:

```
{
“name”:“my name”,
“family”:”my family”
},
{
“name”:“my name1”,
“family”:”my family1”
}
```

But when I call same api with different parameter I get same JSON but with the different type for example an empty array :

```
[]
```

How can create a data model for this type of response in kotlin?

Comment: The first response is invalid json. please post a valid json. otherwise its just a backend-issue.